# Caused by: com.amazonaws.services.sqs.model.QueueDoesNotExistException: The specified queue does not exist for this wsdl version

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I am trying to implement the SimpleQueueService of AWS. I have created the Queue in US-east-2 region by the name: "tradein-tire-promotionsOrders-Alpha-USAmazon". I have mentioned in the xml also , to consider region us-east-2 like this:

```
<bean id="sqsEndPoint_USAmazon" class="java.lang.String">
        <constructor-arg value="https://sqs.us-east-2.amazonaws.com" />
    </bean>
```

The beans which I have created is:

```
<bean name="promotionsOrdersQueuePoller"
        class="com.amazon.tradein.datarelocationengine.sqs.PromotionsOrdersQueuePoller"
        init-method="init">
        <constructor-arg ref="resourceProvider" />
        <constructor-arg ref="promotionsOrdersQueueMessageHandler" />
        <constructor-arg ref="promotionsOrdersQueueMessageFailureHandler" />
    </bean>


<bean name="promotionsOrdersQueueMessageHandler"
        class="com.amazon.tradein.datarelocationengine.sqs.PromotionsOrdersQueueMessageHandler" />


<bean name="promotionsOrdersQueueMessageFailureHandler"
        class="com.amazon.tradein.datarelocationengine.sqs.PromotionsOrdersQueueMessageFailureHandler" />
```

Now I am still getting the error :

```
Error creating bean with name 'promotionsOrdersQueuePoller' defined in URL [file:/local/home/mshikher/TradeInDataRelocationService/src/TradeInDataRelocationEngine/configuration/spring-configuration/application/sqs.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.amazon.tradein.datarelocationengine.exception.TerminalException: SQS message consumer start failed

Caused by: com.amazonaws.services.sqs.model.QueueDoesNotExistException: The specified queue does not exist for this wsdl version. (Service: AmazonSQS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: AWS.SimpleQueueService.NonExistentQueue;
```

I have read many solutions, but there was one solution only that we need to create the queue in us-east-2 region. I have created that already so please provide me with some other solution.

Comment: where you are passing your queue name "tradein-tire-promotionsOrders-Alpha-USAmazon"? IF you plan to pass sqs url it should be like this  https://sqs.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/AWS-Account-number/"tradein-tire-promotionsOrders-Alpha-USAmazon

Comment: Got this correct by just changing the capital Orders to small case orders in word promotionorders.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Cloud - SQS - The specified queue does not exist for this wsdl version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28081182/spring-cloud-sqs-the-specified-queue-does-not-exist-for-this-wsdl-version)